# Updating @RenderBody using jquery in mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Coming from a webform background using ajax I am trying to create similar with mvc.

I have worked out what the controller, view and models do.

What i would like to do now is that when my user clicks a button an jquery call is made to update the view - hence not refreshing the entire page.

Much like a master/child design in webforms.

I have googled and I have tried a couple of things but I get a 404.  I have checked and i am sure I am calling things correctly.

This is my jquery function:

```
$("#divProductsBanner").click(function () {
    var currentObject = $(this).text();
    $.get('@Url.Action("Lite", "Service")', { theName: currentObject });       
});
```

Where 'Lite' is my view and 'Service' is my controller.

my Service.cs controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Lite()
{
    return View();
}
```

and I have a view called 'Lite' under my 'Service' folder under the 'Views' folder.

when I click that button i get this error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You aré not getting @UrlXX executed but as string that's why you get that url. This script is embedded in the view or a standalone js file? Please include relevant parts of view code

Comment: @tede24 not sure what you mean. What other parts are relevant?

Comment: where are you using the jquery code? Inside js file or in View file?

Comment: @Thangaraja inside a js file.  But should it matter?

Comment: Yes it is. You can not not use C# code there. Move the code to view file or change the URL to "Service/Lite"

Comment: this is not c# code. This JavaScript/jquery

Comment: @Url.Action("Lite", "Service") is not JS code

Comment: I got that example from an accepted answer from Stack Overflow hence this question.  OK, it is RAZOR then. What would be the JavaScript alternative pls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use C# code in JS file. You can render the URL in the hidden field and use it

Something like

```
@Html.Hidden("MyURL", @Url.Action("Lite", "Service"))
```

In js

```
$("#divProductsBanner").click(function () {
    var currentObject = $(this).text();
    $.get($("#MyURL").val(), { theName: currentObject });       
});
```

Refer the links and change your code accordingly.

[Asp.Net Mvc Url.Action in external js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640559/asp-net-mvc-url-action-in-external-js-file)

[Use Seprate js File And use Url Helpers in it with ASP.NEt MVC 3 and Razor View Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922041/use-seprate-js-file-and-use-url-helpers-in-it-with-asp-net-mvc-3-and-razor-view)

Comment: nothing actually happens!  The uri is :/service/Lite' ok but no navigation.

Comment: the JS script is being called from within my shared layout if that makes a difference?

Comment: Open the browser console and see if there is any call triggered to that URL

Comment: yes, that is the 1st thing i did.  I had to unaccept the answer because I cannot get it to work. I am sure the error is mine but I am trying to trace..

Comment: the status '200' but the page does not refresh

Comment: No. There wont be a redirect. $.get will go and get the details

Comment: Are you expecting a page redirect? Then you need to use window.location = URL;

Comment: so, using Windows.location will that refresh the whole page or the @RenderBody contents?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103025/discussion-between-thangaraja-and-andrew-simpson).

Comment: i was tired yesterday.  Not in right frame of mind. Your links about partial was spot on - thanks